# Need a solution to pass var variable's value to PHP variable through any script or code in PHP language before I click on submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

In this form, the dropdown box of project will changes the list of module dropdown by the script. I got the value of module list in a text field where **id='mm'** and an alert box also shows value after selection changes.
My query is that I need that value into a PHP variable before submitting the form. Here is my PHP code,

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
global $username;
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];

    include_once('DBconnection.php');
?>

/*--code continues--*/

<?php
/* textfiled in form where id='mm' and it has taken value from module selection after change and alert value in variable mod_val by script. but I want that varaible's value to be pass into a PHP varaible before I hit submit button.
<script> var mod_val </script> ----><?php $module_val; ?> "if this should be possible then let me know any solution." */

$module_val = var mod_val; //how this could be done before hitting on the submit button.

if(isset($_POST['btn-adding']))
{
    $projects = $_POST['pro'];
    echo $projects;
}
}
?>
```

```js
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  

$("#state-list option").filter(function() {    
       return $(this).val() == $("#mm").val(); 
    }).attr('selected', true);  
   
$("#state-list").live("change", function() {

$("#mm").val($(this).find("option:selected").attr("value"));
var mod_val = $("#mm").val();
alert("val===="+mod_val);
});
}); 
</script>
```

```html
<html>
<div class="container">
<form method="post">
<label>Project</label>
                   <span class="txt-val-drops project"><select name="pro" id="country-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getModule(this.value);">
                       <option value="select" selected="selected">Select Project</option>
     <?php
                    foreach($results as $country) {
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $country["fiprojectid"]; ?>"><?php echo $country["fvprojectname"]; ?></option>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                       </select>
</span>
<span class="txt-val-drops module"><select name="mod" id="state-list" class="demoInputBox">
                                <option value="selected" selected="selected">Select Module</option>
                                </select>
</span>
<input type="text" id="mm" name="modid" placeholder="module price." value="" />
<span class="btn-adding"><input type="submit" name="adding" value="Save" /></span>
</form>
</div>
</html>
```

Any how we can get the value from var variable of script and pass that value to a php varaiable before submit the form or refresh the page. I want to use that value in php code for further db queries.

Comment: The question isn't clear. Why not pass the value WITH the form and process the form (and this won't resolve the costraint "before refreshing the page) or use a javascript httprequest ?

Comment: Dear Sir, I need the textbox value where id='mm' into a PHP variable before reloading the page or submit the form. Now you can better understand. @RiccardoBonafede

Comment: The question isn't clear, but I'll start with the obvious, PHP is a server-side script and JavaScript is client side. You can't pass a JavaScript var into PHP. If you want to run another SQL query before the form is submitted or page refreshed you could take the value of 'mm'  and use AJAX to send the value to server then get data back into JavaScript from a server side PHP file that will do your queries.

Comment: Ok, dear @Blueline, Sir, I will use the query after hit on submit,
but I want the value of 'mm' into PHP variable before submit. Will you put here some code with AJAX that will help me out?

Comment: please help  me out here anybody.

Comment: @JoyRocky as I mentioned previously you can't get your variable into PHP without refreshing the page. Can you explain why you need mm as a PHP variable before submit? Then I might be able to make an alternative suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Please add `AJAX` call to set the value in `SESSION` and onSu`enter code here`ccess (callback) submit the form.
This is a ProtoType and not complete code as I don't have all the required setup.

```
$("button").click(function(){
  doValidation();
  var mm = $("#mm").val();

  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "setmm.php",
    data: { mm: mm }
  })
  .done(function( msg ) {
    // Give a Call to AJAX with method as post to do store the value OR do any other job by calling a function
  });
})
```

On PHP file

1. Validate
2. `$mm = sanitize($_POST['mm']); $_SESSION['mm']= $mm;`

Comment: Low quality answer, more like a comment at this moment. Should add some example code on how to achieve this

Comment: Hello @Sameer, Please put some code here that will help.

Comment: @Sameer, How to use thIs function properly. I try a lot but not working in my file. please let me know how to use this function, I don't use Ajax before. so please help me with the proper example here, man thanks!!!

Comment: @Sammer, I don't Ajax before please help me for the solution mate!

Comment: @JoyRocky : I will not be able to give you all the code as I am not sure what you want to do, but you can search for jQuery AJAX you will get the idea about AJAX. All The Best.